# ReactJS: How do i display the retrieved post json response to the same form component which i used to submit the value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

thank you in advance for helping.
I am working on a crawler which I want to work in the following steps:

1. The user enters the seed url (front-end)
2. The user press the submit button (front-end)
3. The seed url will be processed at the express backend which will return a response in json (backend)
4. Once the seed url has been processed at the backend, json response will be sent back to the same component form and populate the input with the state object name (front-end)

**I am currently having trouble with step no.4** where I managed to return the retrieved post json response from express backend but I'm not sure how to make it display back in the component after the **handleSubmi**t function.

Here is my form:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Crawler extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        seedURL: '',
    };
}

handleInputChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let name = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value;

    // Do a set state
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
};

handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // The seed url taken from the input
    const seedURL = this.state;
    console.log("SEED URL: ", seedURL);

    // Take the seedURL and send to API using axios
    const url = "/api";

    // Send data using axios
    axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] ='application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
    try {
        axios
        // url - represents the backend url from express
        // seedURL - is the seed url that we want to send to the backend
        .post(url, seedURL)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(err.data);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};

state = {
    loading: true,
    retail: null
}

render() {
    return(
        // Start of crawler form
        <div className="crawler-form">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h2>Web Crawler</h2>

                <div className="url">
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="SEED URL"
                        name="seedURL"
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Crawl" />      
            </form>
            <h3>Business Information</h3>

            <div className="retail-style">

                <div className="name">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Business Name" name="name" value={/* how do i retrieve the value */} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        // End of Crawler form
    );
}
}
export default Crawler;
```

Comment: What to want to do with the response , update Business Name field?

Comment: I just wanted to display the business field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React will re-render your component any time the state changes.  So the easy way to do this would be to add a property to the state that will hold the response:

```
this.state = {
    seedURL: '',
    response: null,
    error: null,
};
```

Then, when you get the response from the request, you update the state:

```
  axios
    .post(url, seedURL)
    .then((res) => {
        this.setState({response: res, error: null});
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        this.setState({error: err, response: null});
    });
```

And then in your render method, you'll need to do something with the response:

```
render(){
  const bizName = this.state.response ? this.state.response.data.name : "";

  return(
    //... other jsx
    <div className="name">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Business Name" name="name" value={bizName} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to update the input value based on the response:

```
...
.then((res) => {
      document.querySelector('input[name="name"]')[0].value = response.data;
})
...
```

I assume that `response.data` is a text value, if its not, then you have to provide more information about `response.data`. like providing  console.log(response.data) in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await for the promise.

First, make the handleSubmit method async:

```
handleSubmit = async (e) => {...
```

Then make sure you wait for the response from post request:

```
await response = axios.post(url, seedURL);
```

and set the data in the response to the component state.

```
this.setState({ value: response.data.value });
```

Finally, make sure use use the value in the state:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Business Name" name="name" value={this.state.value} />
```